# Forwarding all unknown methods calls and properties usage to special functions in C++

Tags: c++, methods, reflection, properties, attributes

In C++ if I have object of some class `Class obj;` I want to be able to intercept and process calls of methods of any names and arguments like `obj.add(123)`, also to process any properties usage like `auto x = obj.value;`.

The thing is that I don't know what method or property names will be used, e.g. one may use `obj.abc(1, 2, true)` or `auto x = obj.xyz;`.

So if somebody called `obj.abc(1, 2, true)` I want next method to be called with args `("abc", 1, 2, true)`:

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::any ProcessMethod(std::string const & method_name, Args && ... args) {/*...*/}
```

or if property was used `auto x = obj.xyz;` I want next method to be called with `("xyz")` argument:

```
std::any ProcessProperty(std::string const & property_name) {/*...*/}
```

Those two methods above use runtime approach. Even better would be for me to pass called method or property name at compile time (as compile time fixed string). So that I can find out method return type or property type at compile time, i.e. do (for some special class FixedString holding string at compile time):

```
template <FixedString method_name, typename ... Args>
typename ReturnTypeOf<method_name>::type ProcessMethod(Args && ... args) {/*...*/}

template <FixedString property_name>
typename PropertyTypeOf<property_name>::type & ProcessProperty() {/*...*/}
```

Is that possible anyhow to intercept all calls to unknown methods or properties and forward them to last two methods above?

Of cause I can use next syntax: `obj.call<"abc">(1, 2, true)` and `auto x = obj.prop<"xyz">();` to solve my task, but if it is possible to solve anyhow in C++ I would like to stay with syntax `obj.abc(1, 2, true)` and `auto x = obj.xyz;`.

Is very last syntax above achievable anyhow through C++ reflection or templates magic?

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this. C++ does not work this way. Perhaps you can explain the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about "intercepting all calls to unknown methods or properties", but the problem to which you think the solution involves "intercepting all calls to unknown methods or properties" so this is what you're asking about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik By saying "C++ doesn't work this way" you mean that it can't do such thing because it is not yet implemented or because it is against some design of C++? Because there is D language, it closely related to C++, because it is also very statically typed language and in fact a lot of C++ code is also a valid compilable D code. And D has such method for catching all unknown methods/properties calls, there is special method `R opDispatch(string name, R, Args...)(Args args) {` in D when defined all unknown calls go to it. Why C++ can't have something like this in future?

Comment: It is against the fundamental design of the current and all prior C++ standards. Unfortunately I do not have a crystal ball that might tell me whether anything like this will ever be in C++ in the future. Anything is possible, but if I were to make an edumacated guess, I will say that this will never happen in C++. C++ is not D. Something like this can also be done in Perl, and I believe Python. However C++ is not Perl, and it is not Python.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Alright, that answers my question, I trust your huge C++ experience. Basically such thing is not possible at least in current C++. That what I wanted to know. Then I will have to use syntax `obj.call<"abc">(1, 2, true)` and `auto x = obj.prop<"xyz">();`, at least this is the closest variant I can think of to solve my task.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in C++.  You can't overload the `.` operator in this way (**).  This is more of a dynamic language feature.

If you really wanted, you could write a compiler extension to turn `a.b(arg)` into `a.call("b", arg)` where `b` is known not to be a member of `a`.

** There has been discussion of overloading `.`, but the design won't support what you want.  See: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf

Comment: Although it is a dynamic language feature, actually there is no fundamental reason why C++ can't have such feature too. Because such dispatch function can be totally implemented at compile time. Meaning that there will be totally no overhead of using this dispatch function over using regular method. Inside dispatch function I can write something like `if constexpr(method_name == "add") { return DoAdd(args...); }` and because of constexpr if there will be no overhead in this way of processing a method.